# How to handle Application's OnCreate failure properly?

Tags: android, android-activity, error-handling, initialization

I perform some app global initialization in my Application's OnCreate (a subclass of Application). In some rare occasions this initialization fails. When that happens I used to show an activity with a failure message, but apparently this was a bad idea since this function also being called before my background Service is started, which then launches this "failure" activity out of nowhere.

My current solution is to mark with some flag that the initialization failed, and check it in every activity (or Service) that the app might start with. This solution is also bad, because it requires me to remember to check it in every new component I add (that can be launched).

Does someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

If Application initialization fails, you're screwed. Throw an exception and give up.

As corollaries:

- Keep the Application init as thin as possible - do as little as possible.
- Avoid doing anything that can fail.
- Postpone operations that can fail to a point where you have more options for recovery, such as an Activity's lifecycle.

If you need help with a specific failure, please include it in your question.